# Java: URL encoding to JSON/Map&Lists

Tags: java, json, url

within our Java application, we would like to parse URL encoded strings:

`foo[bar]=value&foo[bar1][baz1]=1&foo[bar1][baz2]2&foo[bar2][]=3&foo[bar2][]=4`

->

`{foo: {bar: "value", bar1: {baz1: 1, baz2: 2}, bar2: [3,4]}}`

I don't mind if the parsed result will be JSON or Map&Lists – I just need to get some sensible parsed response.

I couldn't find any tool to do this, implementation is not simple and I certainly doesn't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Where does this URL encoding of a (hierarchical!) structure come from in the first place? Is this standardized in any way? (I.e. is there some sort of a grammar definition?)

Comment: This is the way javascript encodes any JS object. Of course it is standard.

Comment: @Vojtěch: JavaScript doesn’t encode anything like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any existing solution. A few more details about the structure of the input might be helpful, but here is an implementation based on some more-or-less-educated guesses.

It works as follows:

It splits the input string at `&` to obtain **tokens**, which in turn are split at the `=` to obtain key-value pairs

The **value** is converted to an object based on a pragmatic guess. If it can be parsed into a `Long`, this is done. If it can be parsed into a `Double`, this is done. Otherwise, the value is assumed to be a string.

The **key** is a bit more fiddly, although its structure is very simple. It can, for example, be

```
foo[bar]
foo[bar1][baz1]
foo[bar2][]
```

and these properties can be nested arbitrarily. Therefore, these keys are also tokenized, into a list of strings. Such a list may then be

```
["foo", "bar"]
["foo", "bar1", "baz1"]
["foo", "bar", ""]
```

When the last element of this list is the empty string, then the value should be placed into a `List`. Otherwise, it should be placed into a `Map`. This is done by recursively walking through these tokens, passing along the *value*, and creating intermediate `Map` elements if necessary, until the decision about the last element can be made. Whatever this last element is, the *value* is inserted there.

The implementation does not to any sanity checks, so make sure to only feed it with valid inputs.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class DecodeUrl
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s = "foo[bar]=value&foo[bar1][baz1]=1&foo[bar1][baz2]=2&foo[bar2][]=3&foo[bar2][]=4";
        Map<String, Object> result = decode(s);
        print(result, "");
    }

    private static void print(Map<?, ?> map, String indent)
    {
        for (Entry<?, ?> entry : map.entrySet())
        {
            Object key = entry.getKey();
            Object value = entry.getValue();
            if (value instanceof Map<?, ?>)
            {
                Map<?, ?> next = (Map<?, ?>) value;
                System.out.println(indent + key + " : ");
                print(next, indent + "  ");
            } 
            else
            {
                System.out.println(indent + key + " : " + value 
                    + " (type " + value.getClass().getSimpleName() + ")");
            }
        }
    }

    private static Map<String, Object> decode(String s)
    {
        Map<String, Object> result = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        String tokens[] = s.split("&");
        for (String token : tokens)
        {
            int equalsIndex = token.indexOf('=');
            String key = token.substring(0, equalsIndex);
            String valueString = token.substring(equalsIndex+1);
            Object value = processValue(valueString);
            add(result, tokenize(key), value);
        }
        return result;
    }


    private static void add(
        Map<String, Object> target, List<String> path, Object value)
    {
        if (path.size() == 2)
        {
            String parentName = path.get(0);
            String propertyName = path.get(1);
            if (propertyName.isEmpty())
            {
                List<Object> list = getList(target, parentName);;
                list.add(value);
            }
            else
            {
                Map<String, Object> map = getMap(target, parentName);
                map.put(propertyName, value);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            String propertyName = path.get(0);
            Map<String, Object> map = getMap(target, propertyName);
            target.put(propertyName, map);
            add(map, path.subList(1, path.size()), value);
        }
    }

    private static List<Object> getList(
        Map<String, Object> map, String name)
    {
        Object object = map.computeIfAbsent(name, 
            e -> new ArrayList<Object>());
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Object> result = (List<Object>) object;
        return result;
    }


    private static Map<String, Object> getMap(
        Map<String, Object> map, String name)
    {
        Object object = map.computeIfAbsent(name, 
            e -> new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>());
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, Object> result = (Map<String, Object>) object;
        return result;
    }


    private static List<String> tokenize(String key)
    {
        String s = key.replaceAll("\\[", ".");
        String t = s.replaceAll("\\]", "");
        return Arrays.asList(t.split("\\.", -1));
    }

    private static Object processValue(String valueString)
    {
        Long longValue = asLong(valueString);
        if (longValue != null)
        {
            return longValue;
        }
        Double doubleValue = asDouble(valueString);
        if (doubleValue != null)
        {
            return doubleValue;
        }
        return valueString;
    }

    private static Long asLong(String string)
    {
        try
        {
            return Long.parseLong(string);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static Double asDouble(String string)
    {
        try
        {
            return Double.parseDouble(string);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The example decodes the input that was given in the question, and prints the result:

```
foo : 
  bar : value (type String)
  bar1 : 
    baz1 : 1 (type Long)
    baz2 : 2 (type Long)
  bar2 : [3, 4] (type ArrayList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like apache http commons to get a List (https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html)

```
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.utils.URLEncodedUtils

String url = "https://www.url.com/page.html?a=1&b=2&c=3&c=3a";
List<NameValuePair> params = URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI(url), "UTF-8");

params.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I need a general solution, getting a list is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the structure of the thing I would prefer to use oop.

for instance if your string

foo[bar]=value&foo[bar1][baz1]=1&foo[bar1][baz2]=2&foo[bar2][]=3&foo[bar2][]=4

is a representation of the foo object you can just split it a couple times, throw it in a foo object and then use a package like gson to convert an object to json

```
public class asdf {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String urlString = args[0];
    System.out.println(urlString);
    String[] arguments = urlString.split("&");
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    for (String s : arguments) {
        String[] s2 = s.split("=");
        String[] s4 = s2[0].split("\\]\\[|\\[|\\]");
        switch (s4[1]) {
            case "bar":
                foo.bar = s2[1];
                break;
            case "bar1":
                foo.bar1.put(s4[2], Integer.parseInt(s2[1]));
                break;
            case "bar2":
                foo.bar2.add(Integer.parseInt(s2[1]));
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println(s4[1] + " is not a known part of foo");
                break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(foo);
}


private static class Foo {
    String bar;
    Map<String, Integer> bar1;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Foo{" +
                "bar='" + bar + '\'' +
                ", bar1=" + bar1 +
                ", bar2=" + bar2 +
                '}';
    }

    ArrayList<Integer> bar2;

    private Foo() {
        bar1 = new HashMap();
        bar2 = new ArrayList<>();
        bar = "";
    }
}
}
```

of course this only works if you know what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't know the structure, I am looking for a general solution.